# bash sort from the end of string

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to sort file by first file, but the last character is the most important.

For example form file:

```
"AAAACTTTTT"                    1       2

"AAAACAAAAA"    1       2       6       4
```

To:

```
"AAAACAAAAA"    1       2       6       4

"AAAACTTTTT"                    1       2
```

I tried:

```
sort -k1,1 file
```

Of course it doesn't work, but I have no idea how I can do this. Could you help me? Mayby some secret flags?

Comment: You can try `rev` which reverse the line (delimiter is "\n"). So you can do it like this `cat file|rev|sort -k1,1 |rev`

Comment: But now I don't know how many is filed and I can't pick field.

Comment: Sorry please more information (I have learnt English but not well)  So I don't understand what you couldn't do

Comment: My English is very poor that can be a problem. I want to sort file contain, that kind of lines as I wrote and field to sort is 1 - "AAACTTT" and I want to sort this as "TTTCAAA".

Comment: Do you want to implement this for each field?

Comment: No only for this one.

Comment: Try this one `cat YourFile|sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/echo -e $(echo \1|rev)\2/g'|bash|sort |sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/echo -e $(echo \1|rev)\2/g'|bash`

Comment: also you can try first part of it to understand how is it working. Firstly try `cat YourFile|sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/echo -e $(echo \1|rev)\2/g'|bash` secondly  try this `cat YourFile|sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/echo -e $(echo \1|rev)\2/g'|bash|sort` this will give you how it is working

Comment: I hope this will help you. The command look like very long but it is as fast as what you expected. There is also `awk` way but I am not enough good in awk.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to sort (group) a list of email addresses by their domain names e.g. all '@xxx.com' then all the '@yyy.com' (solution based on a comment by makgun)

```
rev emailist | sort | rev > emailistsorted
```

to just get uniques

```
rev emailist | sort -u | rev > emailistsorted
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too big, you can do it with GNU `awk`:

```
{
    count = split($1, arr, "");
    key = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        key = arr[i] key;
    }
    lines[key] = $0;
}
END {
    count = asort(lines);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        print lines[i];
    }
}
```